# Windows Phone 8 SQLite Performance

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 application that uses a SQLite database via the managed wrapper.  I have all the components configured properly and it seems to be working correctly.  However, I am noticing that the performance of insert operations are awful.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the performance.  Note that I am using auto-increment for my primary keys, but I don't think that should be a huge factor.

```
[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Not sure why people do this when you can use a native db like sql server compact...

Comment: I want to use SQLite because I plan on having the same app for WinRT and Win Phone 8, and RT does not have SQL Server CE support.

Comment: How many threads are (or can) read and write to the database?

Comment: Right now I have just one going.  I timed an insert of a single row (with 40 cols) and it took .25 sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserts are fast; what is slow is the transaction overhead, especially on badly designed file systems and badly implemented flash chips.

Use explicit transactions, and put as many operations as possible into a single transaction.

Comment: Thanks.  That made a pretty big difference

Comment: I wanted to follow up (I know it is about a year later now).  I moved all my writes into a transaction.  However, I still think it is relatively slow.  I did a test of inserting 1000 entries into a simple table and it took over 2 seconds.  The table has the primary key, three string fields and a byte[] field.  Any other suggestions on how to improve the performance?